# How can I link graph nodes to a dictionary whose keys are the same as the nodes?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using Networkx to build a 2d graph (for "rat in the maze" problem). I have created the graph, and when I print the Networkx graph I get the coordinates in (row, column) form. I have similarly created a separate dictionary with the same number of items in (row, column) form, so that they match the graph's node names. Now I simply need to link each dictionary key to the graph so that I can use the value of each key (where the value is the "direction" of travel that I can use). "Link" can mean either literally linking the two objects, or setting attributes of each node in the Networkx graph.

I have tried using `nx.relabel_nodes()` and that gives me errors saying that certain keys are not in the graph when they obviously are.

tl;dr how do I link the graph to a dictionary with the same key names?

If there is a better way to link each node in the graph to its "direction" then please mention that as well (no need to give specific code, since I do still want to learn HOW to do it, I am just looking for direction).

If more information is needed I'll reply with it.

edit:

for example, my networkx graph is declared with

```
row = 2
col = 2
mygraph = nx.grid_2d_graph(row, col)
```

When printed this returns

```
{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)}
```

which is similar to a dictionary. Looking through NetworkX documentation I can see that using `relabel_node()` I can edit each node using a dictionary of similar structure:

```
mydict = {(0,0): l, (0,1): r, (1,0): u, (1,1): d} #may have mussed up the structure, but this is a dict
```

by doing

```
nx.relabel_nodes(mygraph, mydict, False)
```

but this returns an error saying that certain nodes are not in the graph.

Comment: if u provide a sample data and your effort and expected output . it will be easy to draw a solution

Comment: I edited the post to include sample I/O and code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you use relabel_nodes:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.grid_2d_graph(2, 2)

In [3]: G.nodes()
Out[3]: [(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1)]

In [4]: mapping = {(0,0): 'l', (0,1): 'r', (1,0): 'u', (1,1): 'd'}

In [5]: nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping).nodes()
Out[5]: ['d', 'l', 'r', 'u']
```